# tutorial/1.4/beginner/build world problem with saving

Tags: gazebo-1.4, gazebo-tutorial

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

Thanks for your help in advance :)

I've installed gazebo 1.4 from source on a gentoo machine.

I created a world and placed some static objects in it.  I then deleted a couple of the objects and then saved the world file and closed gazebo.  When I restarted gazebo with the saved world, the objects I deleted were still there.  It happened both the times I tried it.

Also, when I start gazebo, I get some unfamiliar messages and I'm not sure what they mean:

```
$ gazebo  myworld.sdf &
[1] 9426
$ Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.4.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.4.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master.Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 144.124.131.32
Error [World.cc:1471] Unable to find model[__default__]

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 144.124.131.32
SteeringRation[31.412000] MaxGa[0.200000]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1447/tutorial/1.4/beginner/build-world-problem-with-saving/) by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 73 on 2013-02-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [david_rusbarsky](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/147/david_rusbarsky/) on 2013-02-19**:
I ran into similar issues (if not the same one) http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/838/save-as-does-not-seem-to-work-as-expected-in-drc/

**Comment by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on 2013-02-21**:
Yes, looks to be the same issues there.  Hope it is being looked into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Issue is here: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/563/fix-saving-worlds

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0